# love2d - file doesnt exist but it does

Tags: lua, love2d

I am making a platformer game in Love2D, and I created my own lua script that processes level files.
I used `dofile` in `levelprocessor.lua` and in `main.lua`, i `require()` it and the module sucessfully loads.

However, when I try to process the level (`level1.lua`), it says the file isn't found. But the file exists in the same directory as `levelprocessor.lua` and `main.lua`.

Here is my code:

levelprocesser.lua:

```
local blocks = {
["1"]=(love.graphics.newImage("blocks/grassdirt/grass.png")) -- singular piece of grass
}

local mod={
}

function mod.placeBlock(blockID, posx, posy) 
position = {x=posx*32,y=posy*32}; --blocks are 16x16 and drawn 32x32, and x and y here are in block coordinates, 
-- so a block with ID 1, posx 1, and posy=1, would be a grass block 32 pixels x and 32 pixels y.
for key, value in ipairs(blocks) do
-- glad roblox and that book called Beginning Lua Programming made me understand generic for loops
if key == blockID then 
love.graphics.draw(key, position.x, position.y, 2,2);
else
error("Error in processing level file")
end
end
end

function mod.processFile(fileDir) 
assert(type(fileDir) == "string", "error in function processFile in file levelprocessor.lua: argument 1 must be ")
local level = dofile(fileDir);
for i,v in ipairs(level) do
placeBlock(v.blockID, v.posx, v.posy)
end
end
return mod
```

main.lua:

```
levelprocessor = require "levelprocessor" -- remember kids, do require without file extension
function love.load()
healthbar = love.graphics.newImage("ui/Untitled.png")
good_health = love.graphics.newQuad(0, 0, 100, 36, healthbar:getDimensions())
caution_health = love.graphics.newQuad(100,36,102, 36, healthbar:getDimensions())
warning_health = love.graphics.newQuad(102,36,204,36,healthbar:getDimensions())
grass_top_singular = love.graphics.newImage("blocks/grassdirt/grass.png")
 end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(grass_top_singular, 0,568,0,2,2); -- 600-32=558... mental math, so im not sure if it is truly correct
    levelprocessor.processFile("level1.lua")
end
```

The error itself is:

```
cannot open level1.lua: No such file or directory

Traceback

[C]: in function 'dofile'
levelprocessor.lua:22: in function 'processFile'
main.lua:12 in function 'draw'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: `require` searches in configured paths. `dofile` doesn't. `dofile` uses the *processes* working directory.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Minimal code I tried: In `main.lua`: `function love.load() dofile "foo.lua" dofile "foo/bar.lua" end`; in `foo.lua`: `print "foo works"`; in `foo/bar.lua`: `print "foo/bar works"`; running this will print "foo works" and "foobar works". What version of love2d are you on?

Comment: Ah, yes – running from a different directory means it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
dofile( f )
```

by

```
assert( love.filesystem.load( f ) )( )
```

`love.filesystem.`* will look in the source directory (and a few other places), not in the working directory.